# posebone.keyframe_insert() not being stored in animation, only armature keyframes stored successfully, any ideas?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

my first post here. I've been tearing my hair out on the steep learning curve with manipulating bones and armatures in Blender 2.8. I'm very very close to the solution but have a hit a stumbling block.

As a background I am importing data from a simulation I have carried out in other software (Rhino3D) which I have stored in a json file. I have a list of "frame_data" stored in the "frames" list. Each frame has a list of "stems" which are the elements I am animating each with its own armature. With the data from the json file I insert keyframes for the armature's location and orientation and then I loop through the pose bones of the armature inserting keyframes.

I have learned the hard way how to format the data and get the orientation of the matrices just right. The final stumbling block here is that the armature stores its keyframes and the animation plays back well after I have run the script, but the bones themselves are static and take the pose of the **final frame** only. The empties that I have used as an intermediate step also animate correctly, so I definitely have the data I need, it just doesn't seem to have any effect when I call

```
stem_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=frame_no)
```

I have already been caught out by the "gotcha" of needing to call `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`, is there a similar issue here? Does anybody know?

Is it because of the nesting of my loops at all?

```
for frame_no, frame_data in enumerate(frames):
    print("Current frame: {}".format(frame_no))
    for stem_idx, stem in enumerate(frame_data):
        
        if stem_idx>0:
            continue
        #if frame_no>10:
        #    continue
        
        if stem["type"]==0:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')    
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all objects
            
            curr_name = stem["name"]
            print("Current stem: " + curr_name)
            
            curr_arm_name = curr_name + 'Armature'
            current_stem_armature =  bpy.data.objects[curr_arm_name]
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = current_stem_armature
            
            #keyframing of root location of armature (stem node 0)
            # X, Y, and Z location to set
            location = stem["root_loc"]
            root_rots = stem["root_rots"]
            #print(location)
            
            #OK this section is working!!
            current_stem_armature.rotation_mode  = 'XYZ'
            current_stem_armature.rotation_euler = root_rots[0],root_rots[1],root_rots[2]
            current_stem_armature.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=frame_no)
            current_stem_armature.location = location[0],location[1],location[2]
            current_stem_armature.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_no)
            
            bpy.context.view_layer.update()
            
            #bone_transforms = stem["bone_transforms"]
            bone_rots = stem["bone_rots"]
            bone_locs = stem["bone_locs"]
            
            for bone_idx, stem_bone in enumerate(bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones):
                print(stem_bone.name)
                if bone_idx>0:   
                    b_name = stem_bone.name
                    curr_empty_name = curr_name + "_" + b_name+"_empty"
                    # If we're on the first frame
                    if frame_no==0:
                        curr_empty = bpy.data.objects.new( curr_empty_name, None )
                        curr_empty.empty_display_size = 0.01
                        curr_empty.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
                        curr_empty.location = 0,0,0
                        def_coll.objects.link( curr_empty )
                        bpy.context.view_layer.update()
                    
                    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
                    
                    curr_empty_ob = bpy.data.objects[curr_empty_name]
                    #change empty then apply its transform to bone
                    bone_rot = bone_rots[bone_idx-1]
                    bone_loc = bone_locs[bone_idx-1]
                    curr_empty_ob.rotation_mode  = 'XYZ'
                    curr_empty_ob.rotation_euler = bone_rot[0],bone_rot[1],bone_rot[2]
                    curr_empty_ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=frame_no)
                    curr_empty_ob.location = bone_loc[0]/1000,bone_loc[1]/1000,bone_loc[2]/1000
                    curr_empty_ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_no)
                    
                    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
                    
                    input_mw = curr_empty_ob.matrix_world
                    
                    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
                                        
                    output_mw = current_stem_armature.convert_space(pose_bone=stem_bone, 
                                                    matrix=input_mw, 
                                                    from_space='WORLD', 
                                                    to_space='POSE')  
                    #print("output_mw")
                    #print(output_mw)
                    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
                    stem_bone.matrix  = output_mw 
                    #stem_bone.rotation_euler = output_mw.to_euler()
                    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
                    
                    #bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_no)
                    stem_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=frame_no)
                    
                    print(b_name+ "  rotation_euler  frame no  " + str(frame_no))
                    print(stem_bone.rotation_euler)
                    
                    
                    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
                    
                    stem_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_no)
                    
            
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')    
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all objects
```